# solve equation using a list as coefficient

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve this equation :

```
solve[-Log2[0.001]/1000 == k*Log2[k/q] + (1 - k)*Log2[(1 - k)/(1 - q)], q]
```

k is a value from a list

```
v1 = {7,8,9}
```

So the desired results should be

```
q={somevaule1, somevaule2, somevalue2} corresponding to different choice of k in v1
```

I searched online but no luck. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

This will do it

```
v1 = {7, 8, 9};
FindRoot[-Log2[10^-3]/1000==#*Log2[#/q]+(1-#)*Log2[(1-#)/(1-q)],{q,5}]&/@v1
```

It complains about not being able to get the accuracy that it wants, but you may be able to ignore that. Giving it a WorkingPrecision or an AccuracyGoal option can perhaps overcome that. I changed the 0.001 to 10^-3 because that was the only number in your post that had a decimal point and I hoped by making that an exact fraction it might get rid of the warnings about accuracy, but that wasn't enough.

What that does is turn the whole FindRoot into a function, using # with & as the variable, and then uses Map (which has a shorthand of /@) to use that function on each item in your v1 list and returns you the list of the results. You could write exactly the same thing with

```
Map[FindRoot[....]&, v1]
```

if that is more understandable for you.